# How to document a method in R using Roxygen2 when the class and generic live in another package?

Tags: r, documentation, r-s4, roxygen2

How does one document a method for a class defined in another package?

For example, I've written a method for the QDNAseqSignals class defined in the [QDNAseq](https://github.com/ccagc/QDNAseq?tab=readme-ov-file). I want to document this method using roxygen2.

Section A (Code in my new package):

```r
#' A cool new plot
#'
#' @description
#' This new plot is great!
#'
#' @importClassesFrom QDNAseq QDNAseqReadCounts QDNAseqCopyNumbers
#' @export anewplot
setMethod("anewplot", signature(x="QDNAseqSignals", y="missing"),
          function (x, y, main=NULL, includeReadCounts=TRUE,...){}
```

Section B (Class in the QDNAseq package):

```r
setClass('QDNAseqSignals',
    contains  = 'eSet',
    prototype = prototype(new('VersionedBiobase',
    versions  = c(classVersion('eSet'), QDNAseq=packageVersion('QDNAseq'))))
)
```

I am unable to get the code in section A to generate documentation properly when calling `devtools::document`. A **plot-QDNAseqSignals-missing-method.Rd** file is generated rather than the expected **plot.Rd** file.

I've tried using other export tags like: @exportMethod.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question to make it short while making sure it doesn't lack any information in the original post. I hope the edit helps the readers.

Comment: @user22080160 (1) The class `QDNAseqSignals` is **unexported** in package `QDNAseq`, so writing a method for that class in your package is not a good approach. (2) The code in Section A referred to a method called `anewplot`, but later on you talked about `plot` function.

Comment: I think these 2 links will help you: [1-Talk in general about documenting S4 class and methods](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-other.html#s4), [2-Use @rdname as an approach for documenting S4](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/reuse.html?q=name#rdname)

Comment: Ah ok, the not a great approach bit makes sense.